# How to apply build.gradle properties from custom standalone plugin to project that applies that plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I have many projects that are using same dependencies and plugins and so on. I've prepared standalone Gradle plugin to avoid doing it in all projects, but I faced one problem.

Let's say that all my projects are using **com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties**

My plugin is able to apply git-properties plugin to project that applies my plugin - that's good, but I want also add some properties for this plugin to target project, I mean something like this:

```
gitProperties {
  dateFormat = 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'
  dateFormatTimeZone = 'Europe/Warsaw'
  keys = [
          'git.branch',
          'git.commit.id.abbrev',
          'git.commit.time',
          'git.dirty',
          'git.commit.message.short'
  ]
}
```

Question: How to add this properties to target build.gradle? It is possible that target project can reuse properties from plugin build.gradle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your plugin configures the project in question and applies the `com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties`, you will have to configure the extension contributed by the underlying plugin.

Given that this plugin registers an extension of type `GitPropertiesPluginExtension`, you need to get access to it and then can configure it (code in Java):

```
// After adding the plugin
GitPropertiesPluginExtension gitExtension = project.getExtensions().getByType(GitPropertiesPluginExtension.class);
gitExtension.keys = // Your list of keys
```